# Sparing Sans before he asks to be spared?

Tags: undertale

What happens if you spare sans in his fight before he asks you to?
What are the options and what happens when you select them?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing different will happen and his fight will continue as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen. If you try to spare him prematurely, he'll continue the fight as planned. The only time in which you can spare him is when he offers to spare you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. He won't say anything, he'll just attack normally, as if you healed or ACTed. Also, when he tries to SPARE you, he will simply say "Friendship... is great, right? Let's stop fighting."

Comment: This answer adds nothing not already said by other answers. Duplicate answers are not helpful and may be deleted.